Multiple period line is broken when same date in react-native-calander
I am using react-native-calendar in one of my applications. It works well with single events and period (range) events separately. However, when a date has both a single event and a period event, the display breaks. For instance, on October 8th, I have a single event ("test3") and a period event ("test4") spanning from October 7th to 8th. In this scenario, the period line for the event breaks, as shown in the attached screenshot.
I have also included the source code for reference.
If you have any solution. Please let me know.
Thanks

import React, { useState, useMemo, useCallback } from 'react';
import { Calendar } from 'react-native-calendars';
import { RRule } from 'rrule';
import moment from 'moment';

const events = [
{
    "id": "Ms9e3VcmcVR",
    "churchId": "AOjIt0W-SeY",
    "groupId": "23EYbkfbEhQ",
    "allDay": false,
    "start": "2024-09-24T06:30:00.000Z",
    "end": "2024-09-24T07:30:00.000Z",
    "title": "Test",
    "description": null,
    "visibility": "public",
    "recurrenceRule": null,
    "exceptionDates": []
},
{
    "id": "tSIRuVzE3C1",
    "churchId": "AOjIt0W-SeY",
    "groupId": "23EYbkfbEhQ",
    "allDay": false,
    "start": "2024-09-27T06:30:00.000Z",
    "end": "2024-09-27T23:34:00.000Z",
    "title": "test1",
    "description": null,
    "visibility": "public",
    "recurrenceRule": null,
    "exceptionDates": []
},
{
    "id": "vyI9OOLIl8l",
    "churchId": "AOjIt0W-SeY",
    "groupId": "23EYbkfbEhQ",
    "allDay": false,
    "start": "2024-10-02T06:30:00.000Z",
    "end": "2024-10-03T01:36:00.000Z",
    "title": "test2",
    "description": null,
    "visibility": "public",
    "recurrenceRule": null,
    "exceptionDates": []
},
{
    "id": "rA0sLMNs4px",
    "churchId": "AOjIt0W-SeY",
    "groupId": "23EYbkfbEhQ",
    "allDay": false,
    "start": "2024-10-07T06:30:00.000Z",
    "end": "2024-10-07T20:34:00.000Z",
    "title": "test4",
    "description": null,
    "visibility": "public",
    "recurrenceRule": null,
    "exceptionDates": []
},
{
    "id": "u9WyJwCAOc-",
    "churchId": "AOjIt0W-SeY",
    "groupId": "23EYbkfbEhQ",
    "allDay": false,
    "start": "2024-10-08T06:30:00.000Z",
    "end": "2024-10-07T18:35:00.000Z",
    "title": "test3",
    "description": null,
    "visibility": "public",
    "recurrenceRule": null,
    "exceptionDates": []
},
{
    "id": "pXJ9N2y15WA",
    "churchId": "AOjIt0W-SeY",
    "groupId": "23EYbkfbEhQ",
    "allDay": false,
    "start": "2024-10-10T06:30:00.000Z",
    "end": "2024-10-10T23:34:00.000Z",
    "title": "Recurring events",
    "description": null,
    "visibility": "public",
    "recurrenceRule": "FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=1;WKST=MO;BYDAY=TH",
    "exceptionDates": []
}
];

const getFullRRule = (event) => {
  let rrule = RRule.fromString(event.recurrenceRule);
  rrule.options.dtstart = new Date(event.start);
  return rrule;
};

const getRange = (event, startDate, endDate) => {
  const start = new Date(event.start);
  const rrule = getFullRRule(event);

  const dates = rrule.between(startDate, endDate);

  dates.forEach(d => {
    d.setHours(start.getHours());
    d.setMinutes(start.getMinutes());
    d.setSeconds(start.getSeconds());
  });

  return dates;
};

const removeExcludeDates = (events) => {
  for (let i = events.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (events[i].exceptionDates?.length > 0) {
      const parsedDates = events[i].exceptionDates.map(d => new Date(d).toISOString());
      if (parsedDates.indexOf(events[i].start.toISOString()) > -1) events.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
}

const App = () => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState('2024-09-24');

  const expandEvents = (events) => {
    const expandedEvents = [];
    const startRange = new Date();
    const endRange = new Date();
    startRange.setFullYear(startRange.getFullYear() - 1);
    endRange.setFullYear(endRange.getFullYear() + 1);

    events.forEach(event => {
      const ev = { ...event };
      ev.start = new Date(ev.start);
      ev.end = new Date(ev.end);
      if (event.recurrenceRule) {
        const dates = getRange(event, startRange, endRange);
        dates.forEach((date) => {
          const ev = { ...event };
          const diff = new Date(ev.end).getTime() - new Date(ev.start).getTime();
          ev.start = date;
          ev.end = new Date(date.getTime() + diff);
          expandedEvents.push(ev);
        });
        removeExcludeDates(expandedEvents);
      }
      else { expandedEvents.push(ev); }
    });
    return expandedEvents;
  };

  const expandedEvents = useMemo(() => expandEvents(events), [events]);

  const markedDates = useMemo(() => {
    const marked = {};

    expandedEvents.forEach(event => {
      const startString = moment(event.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
      const endString = moment(event.end).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
      const isSingleDay = startString === endString;

      if (isSingleDay) {
        // Single-day event
        marked[startString] = {
          startingDay: true,
          endingDay: true,
          color: '#70d7c7',
          textColor: 'white',
          dotColor: 'black',
          marked: true,
        };
      } else {
        // Multi-day event
        if (!marked[startString]) {
          marked[startString] = {
            startingDay: true,
            color: '#70d7c7',
            textColor: 'white',
            dotColor: 'black',
            marked: true,
          };
        }
        if (!marked[endString]) {
          marked[endString] = {
            endingDay: true,
            color: '#70d7c7',
            textColor: 'white',
            dotColor: 'black',
            marked: true,
          };
        }
        const diffInDays = moment(event.end).diff(moment(event.start), 'days');
        for (let i = 1; i < diffInDays; i++) {
          const middleDate = moment(event.start).add(i, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
          if (!marked[middleDate]) {
            marked[middleDate] = { color: '#70d7c7', textColor: 'white' };
          }
        }
      }
    });

    return marked;
  }, [expandedEvents, selected]);

  const onDayPress = useCallback((day) => {
    setSelected(day.dateString);
    console.log("Selected day: ", day.dateString);
  }, []);

  return (
    <Calendar
      current={'2024-09-24'}
      markingType={'period'}
      markedDates={markedDates}
      onDayPress={onDayPress}
      theme={{
        textInactiveColor: '#a68a9f',
        textSectionTitleDisabledColor: 'grey',
        textSectionTitleColor: '#319e8e',
        arrowColor: '#319e8e',
        todayTextColor: 'red',
        selectedDayBackgroundColor: '#5E60CE',
        selectedDayTextColor: 'white',
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default App;

markingType={'multi-period'} is also work same broken line.
const colors = ['green', 'blue', 'purple', 'orange'];

  const markedDates = useMemo(() => {
    const marked = {};
  
    expandedEvents.forEach((event, index) => {
      const startString = moment(event.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
      const endString = moment(event.end).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
      const isSingleDay = startString === endString;
      const color = colors[index % colors.length];
  
      if (isSingleDay) {
        if (!marked[startString]) {
          marked[startString] = { periods: [] };
        }
        marked[startString].periods.push({
          startingDay: true, 
          endingDay: true, 
          color: color 
        });
      } else {
        if (!marked[startString]) {
          marked[startString] = { periods: [] };
        }
        marked[startString].periods.push({
          startingDay: true, 
          color: color 
        });
  
        if (!marked[endString]) {
          marked[endString] = { periods: [] };
        }
        marked[endString].periods.push({
          endingDay: true, 
          color: color 
        });
  
        const diffInDays = moment(event.end).diff(moment(event.start), 'days');
        for (let i = 1; i < diffInDays; i++) {
          const middleDate = moment(event.start).add(i, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
          if (!marked[middleDate]) {
            marked[middleDate] = { periods: [] };
          }
          marked[middleDate].periods.push({
            color: color 
          });
        }
      }
    });
  
    return marked;
  }, [expandedEvents, selected]);

